# Applying OOBE to captured WIM

Tags: windows, sysprep, mdt, wim

Im trying to deploy an OOBE image using MDT Sysprep Task sequence. I have no problem capturing the "golden" image (with all necessary programs and what-not) but the main point of the confusion is **how to deploy the capture in OOBE?**

When I make a new Task Sequence, consisting that golden WIM file, sequence options it still asks me to specify the geolocation, admin properties etc and when the deployment is done the deployment PC heads me to Desktop with all settings configured.

Is there an OOBE option that Im missing, or am I sysprepping the image incorrectly?

Comment: MDT is designed to be a lite or zero touch deployment. An OOBE process is meant to be automated. Doing it otherwise is contrary to MDT's purpose. However, you can edit the unattend file under the task sequence configuration, so you can probably enable OOBE again. As stated this will defeat the purpose of an automated deployment so you might as well not even use MDT as you'll be stuck hand holding the OS again. OOBE occurs before most task sequences complete.

Comment: Are you trying to make it interactive or make it more automated and hands free?

Comment: @ElliotLabs As automated as possible + bring an OOBE expierence to the end user.

Comment: @Jon ok, you should be able to do that by making it a `ZTI` and then running `C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe /oobe` next to last then reboot as the last step.
Tell me if that does it and then I will turn it into an answer.

Comment: Im sorry, I guess I didnt explain my problem correcty. I have no problem building OOBE image (made that using fresh 10 installation, before setting up the OS I went into audit mode, then made all the necessary customizations) The problem is - I captured the image that technically should work as an OOBE, but the Task Sequence prompts me to add details about accounts and so, and when I deploy it, it automatically heads me to Desktop.

Comment: I guess I figured out how to achieve my goal. I will make a custom OOBE image, then capture it with DISM, then make a new Custom Task Sequence containing that OOBE wim and then hope for the best. This might sound dumb, but whatever keeps me going, Im still new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem:
I managed to deploy an OOBE-enabled image by editing **unattended.xml** file, deleted all sections that contained Built-In Administrator Enabling aswell as "trued" all OOBE screens in OOBE section. Altough it would be much easier to deploy golden image just from WDS, I just wanted to know if OOBEing was possible with MDT.

Thanks to everyone that commented, that led me to correct path! :)